# openni_launch + USB 3.0 not working?

Tags: kinect, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

Has anyone noticed that when you plug your Kinect to a USB 3.0 port "roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch" seems to be successful but there is no data published in any of the camera topics?

This happens to me with:

```
Ubuntu 12.04 64bit + Fuerte on Desktop PC
Ubuntu 12.04 64bit + Fuerte on Notebook PC (ASUS U24E)
Ubuntu 11.10 64bit + Electric on Notebook PC (ASUS U24E)
```

If I plug the Kinect to a USB 2.0 port on any of the previous combinations, it works correctly (though it is still a bit buggy on Ubuntu 12.04 + Fuerte).

Has anyone had the same issue? Any way to get it working on USB 3.0?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33746/openni_launch-+-usb-3.0-not-working?/) by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5625 on 2012-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at this [answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/9179/kinect-and-usb-30)

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1